# add method/functions list like visualstudios on netbeans 7 editor toolbars?

Tags: netbeans, netbeans-7

is there any way, to enable a dropdown list of methods or functions, on the Editor Toolbars of NetBeans 7, like VS does? , i mean the toolbar that is inside on the tab of each file when you are editing a code, that has some options like, "last edit, next breakpoint, next bookmark, ..."

In VS is really helpful this feature, to jump of functions o methods more quickly, i know that netbeans has the navigator, but sometimes this help more

Greatings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> is there any way, to enable a dropdown list of methods or functions,
>   on the Editor Toolbars of NetBeans 7, like VS does?

There is no way provided by standard NetBeans IDE offering or certified plugins available in NetBeans Update center, but a NetBeans plugin can be written for doing what is expected in your question.  Has it been done?  In my opinion no, as no one asked till now.  Now that you have asked someone may think of developing such a plugin.

Best way to expedite such request and feature to be added to NetBeans is to add a Request for Enhancement in the NetBeans issue tracker.

> In VS is really helpful this feature, to jump of functions o methods
>   more quickly, i know that netbeans has the navigator, but sometimes
>   this help more

There are many ways to reach specific methods in NetBeans IDE.  You have already listed one and that is Navigator.  Others include GoTo Type [CTRL+O] and GoTo Symbol [CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+O]

Comment: thank for the answer!, i will submit this to Request NetBeans , because i really like that Feature in VS, but i found really helpful the "GoTo Type" feature, honestly i didnt know about this, so thank :D